# Changing own id in pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm developing a Laravel application where I have a posts table, a tags table and a post_tag  table which acts as a pivot table.

Now I need to give all the tags from a post to another post. In other words I need to make:

```
$tags = $post->tags;
```

And change the post_id to each record in the pivot table. I have all the relationships already set.

**EDIT**: this is my code

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class)->withPivot('is_active')->withTimestamps();
    }

}

class Tag extends Model { }
```

The main problem is that I have to keep the is_active value as it is. I just need to replace the post_id from the pivot table where post_id equals the one I want to override (I know I could make a raw query but I'm trying to avoid it)

**EDIT 2**:

I made it work this way but I still prefer an object oriented way

```
DB::table('post_tag')->where('post_id', $post_a->id)->update(['post_id' => $post_b->id]);
```

Comment: Could you show how are your clases and relationships?

Comment: Updated, check it out

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
$tags = $post->tags;

//convert tags to IDs only for upcoming steps
... //an array of IDs

$post->tags()->sync($tags); //remove the tags from this post
$post2->tags()->sync($tags); // add the tags to this post
```

This should get you to the right tracks.

**Update**

If it was only one, this would do

```
$post2->tags()->attach($tag, ['is_active' => true]);
$post2->tags()->->sync([1 => ['is_active' => true], 2 => ['is_active' => true]);
```

You can try to adapt the example above.
But I have no idea how to do it with an array of IDs.

Comment: I updated my answer. You copy the IDs to the new post. attach them. And delete from the old post. If it doesn't help, all good.

Comment: It wont keep the is_active field value

Comment: Check my update. If it doesn't work, good luck mate. I hope you find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `updateExistingPivot` of Eloquent, from the laravel documentation:

> If you need to update an existing row in your pivot table, you may use updateExistingPivot method. This method accepts the pivot record foreign key and an array of attributes to update:
>
> ```
> $user = App\User::find(1);
>
> $user->roles()->updateExistingPivot($roleId, $attributes);
> ```